# Connection must be valid and open when using ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm building a configuration form in c# (visual studio 2017) with a MySQL db. I want to store folder paths in the database. I'm getting a "Connection must be valid and open" error but when I comment out "cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();" I don't get the error. If you could show me what i'm doing wrong, I would realy appreciate it. If you could give me a code example it would be great also. Here is my code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

        ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());

        string a = textBox1.Text;
        string b = textBox2.Text;
        string c = textBox4.Text;
        string escapedPath = a.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("'", @"\'");
        string escapedPath1 = b.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("'", @"\'");
        string escapedPath2 = c.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("'", @"\'");
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("update shopmanager.paths set path_to_clients = '" + escapedPath + "',path_to_employee = '" + escapedPath1 + "',path_to_procedures = '" + escapedPath2 + "';");

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. I've taken the liberty of removing your tags from your title (see [Tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for why) and removed the `visual-studio` tag from your question (this tag should only be used to ask questions about Visual Studio, not about code you write within Visual Studio).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you comment-out `cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();` nothing is happening, so an error is unlikely ;-)

> Connection must be valid and open

This error states that there is no open connection object bound to the command. Although you open the connection, you never assign it to the command (different commands could have different connections).

So; you need to assign the connection to the command:

```
cmd2.Connection = con;
```

or, more common, when constructing your command:

```
MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("your sql goes here", con);
```

Answer (score 2):

*Connection must be valid and open* always indicates that `MySqlCommand` not associated to any active connection when `ExecuteNonQuery()` method executes or proper `MySqlConnection` instance is never supplied to respective command, even the connection is already open.

Hence, it is better to set up your `UPDATE` query so that it is easier to read like this:

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString()))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(@"update shopmanager.paths 
    set path_to_clients = @escapedPath, path_to_employee = @escapedPath1,
    path_to_procedures = @escapedPath2 where ...", con))
    {
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@escapedPath", a.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("'", @"\'"));
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@escapedPath1", b.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("'", @"\'"););
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@escapedPath2", c.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("'", @"\'"));

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Or set `CommandText` and `Connection` properties separately (also with parameters, avoid concatenating values at all):

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString()))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        cmd2.Connection = con;
        cmd2.CommandText = "update shopmanager.paths set path_to_clients = @escapedPath, path_to_employee = @escapedPath1, path_to_procedures = @escapedPath2 where ...";
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@escapedPath", a.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("'", @"\'"));
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@escapedPath1", b.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("'", @"\'"););
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@escapedPath2", c.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("'", @"\'"));

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `using` statements are useful to dispose connection objects immediately after successful update.